# Flow - Dynamically Populate Display Text

Tags: flow, loginflow

I'm using a flow paired with a login flow to display a monthly release notifications to users when they log in to SF. The issue is that I'm finding it hard to format the login flow message in the way I want to. When you add Display Text to a screen in a flow, it's really hard to make the formatting look good.

Here's my question:

**Can I create some kind of variable and insert it into the screen's display text so that it shows text from a different place in Salesforce**, like a custom label or even a specific record's field value? I'm trying to find a way to easily update the text and formatting of the message without having to update the flow each month.

Thanks,
Rochelle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple merge values in a flow, so it's entirely possible to do things like what you're talking about. For retrieving labels, you apparently can't merge those in directly, so you'd have to use the [InvocableMethod](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm) interface to set a flow variable before using the label. For records, you can query the record via Fast Lookup, then merge that within the output text's display area using the usual {!recordVar.FieldName__c} syntax.

Answer (score 0):

To deal w formatting you can use a text template to populate a text variable and display that variable in a screen.  You can run queries and loops and other fun things to gather the data.

See this post on developer.force.com where yoda guided me on how to do so

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AwtcIAC